# powershellでの＆演算子の使い方について

Tags: node.js, powershell

mdnのwebページで「スケルトンwebサイトを実行する」というタスクに取り掛かっています。（以下にサイトURLを記載）
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website
指示通りにpowershellにコマンドを入力していたのですが，アプリケーション実行時に次のようなエラーが発生しました。

入力コマンド

```
SET DEBUG=express-locallibrary-tutorial:* """&""" npm start
```

エラー内容

```
発生場所 行:1 文字:43
+ SET DEBUG=express-locallibrary-tutorial:* & npm start
+                                           ~
アンパサンド (&) 文字は許可されていません。& 演算子は、今後使用するために予約されています。アンパサンドを二重引用符で囲
み ("&")、文字列の一部として渡してください。
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

エラー内容から＆演算子が特殊文字ゆえにエスケープできていないと考え，バッククオートを前につけて再度実行しました。結果はつぎのとおりです。

入力コマンド

```
SET DEBUG=express-locallibrary-tutorial:* `& npm start
```

エラー内容

```
Set-Variable : 引数 'npm' を受け入れる位置指定パラメーターが見つかりません。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ SET DEBUG=express-locallibrary-tutorial:* `& npm start
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable]、ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

どうすればアプリケーションを実行できるでしょうか？

実行環境は次のとおりです。
Node.js:ver 11.13.0
アプリケーションジェネレータ：express-generator
os:windows 11 Home
Powershell:ver 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShellではなくコマンドプロンプト(CMD.EXE)を使ってください。

一応、この部分は参考チュートリアルの[英語版](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website#creating_the_project)の通り、下記のPowerShellスクリプトで動くようです。

```
$ENV:DEBUG = "express-locallibrary-tutorial:*"; npm start
```

しかしその後のNote(下記引用)の通り、チュートリアルでコマンドプロンプトの使用が公式に推奨されています。

> Note: Powershell commands are not covered further in this tutorial (The provided "Windows" commands assume you're using the Windows CMD prompt.)

#### Noteが出た経緯

この部分のPowerShell対応は [PowerShell command missing, only has CMD and does not tell you that its CMD only #1580](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/1580)で提案されました。
上記の懸案は[Fix up powershell and flaws #1601](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/1601)で対応されましたが、日本語版には反映されていません。
その後に[Issue with "Express Tutorial Part 2: Creating a skeleton websi…": … #1699](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/1699)は、これ以上PowerShell対応しない旨の結論でクローズされています。

これ以降のセクションもPowerShellの造詣が深くないと同様のエラーが出てきますので、繰り返しになりますがコマンドプロンプト(CMD.EXE)を使いましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。コマンドプロンプトにて実行したところアプリケーションを実行できました。noteが出てきた経緯についても載せていただきまことにありがとうございます。